# Combining two pointcuts but with parameters (if is possible)

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop

For a Spring application project, before to `delete` or `update` something (an entity) I want before check if that object exists.

I have the following:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.PersonaServiceImpl.deleteOne(String)) 
&& args(id)")
public void deleteOnePointcut(String id){}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.PersonaServiceImpl.updateOne(com.manuel.jordan.domain.Persona)) 
&& args(persona)")
public void updateOnePointcut(Persona persona){}
```

If I use:

```java
@Around("PersonaServicePointcut.deleteOnePointcut(id)")
public void delete(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, String id) throws Throwable{
    if(id != null){
        personaService.findOneById(id);
        //throw error if not exists, 
        //has no sense delete something that does not exists
        ...
    }
...
```

works.

Just how playing I've tried the following (a combination of two pointcuts shown above):

```java
@Around("PersonaServicePointcut.deleteOnePointcut(id) ||
               PersonaServicePointcut.updateOnePointcut(persona)")
    public Object mai(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, String id, Persona persona){
        if(id != null){
            personaService.findOneById(id);
            //throw error
        }

        if(persona != null){
            personaService.findOneById(persona.getId());
            //throw error
        }

        //...

        proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

        return null;
    }
```

But I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
error at ::0 inconsistent binding
```

I am assuming because either the 2nd or 3rd parameter is null since we have an `OR`. I mean all the parameters should be assigned.

I have read some tutorials about combining pointcuts, but all of them without parameters.

*Just curious* if is possible accomplish this approach. If yes how?

Comment: I think this is not possible because it will result in an unbound parameter (either ```id``` or ```persona```).

Comment: Fabian is right. It is impossible with that syntax in AspectJ, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34426950/1082681) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36193862/1082681). In those answers you can also find workarounds for factoring out common functionality and calling them from two or more advices.

Comment: Ok. I understand, proceed to post the answer to mark how solved. Thanks.