# AspectJ pointcut matching arguments (args()) is not matching correctly

Tags: java, aspectj

I've got an pointcut that I am trying to use with LTW.  I have 2 methods that I am trying to advise, each with a different parameter list.  However, they both have a single common parameter that I want.

These are the method signatures I want to advise:

```
   public static WorkflowModifierFlags authenticateUser(String username, String password, String ip, boolean webGUI, boolean realAuthentication)

   public static boolean loginJAAS(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String username, String password, HttpSession session)
```

I've tried the following pointcut/advice, but it is failing; the username variable is sometimes getting injected with the IP address (ie: the args() from the first pointcut).

```
@Before("(execution(public static * business.security.service.LoginManagerHelper.authenticateUser(..)) && args( username, ..)) || "
        + "(execution(public static * webapp.util.LoginManagerAction.loginJAAS(..)) && args( *, *, username, ..))" )
public void setUsername(JoinPoint jp, String username) {
    // inject the username into the MDC
    MDCUtils.setUsername(username);
}
```

I would have expected that the `args()` parameter is associated to the execution() method, but sometimes it would appear that it is "confused", and gives me the IP instead of the username.

Am I using AspectJ incorrectly, or is this a bug in the LTW?  I'm running AspectJ 1.6.13

Comment: As confirmed by Andy Clement in the aspectj-user mailing list, this is a bug in the AJ complier/weaver.  A bug has been reported at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509235 to track the issue.

Comment: As a side note: Are you ready to upgrade to AspectJ 1.8.x then? I guess Andy is not going to backport the fix to the outdated 1.6.x version. I do wonder why you use 1.6.13 at all. Are there any reasons forcing you to do this?

Comment: @kriegaex I was unable to get aspectj 1.8 working on my jb4 container with LTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AspectJ 1.8.9 has the same behavior. One solution/workaround to this would be to split the advice into two using a different pointcut for each case, then delegate the logic you want to do with the username to avoid code duplication. It would look similar to this:

```
@Before("execution(public static * business.security.service.LoginManagerHelper.authenticateUser(..)) && args( username, ..)")
public void pointcut1(String username) {
    doSomethingWithUsername(username);
}

@Before("execution(public static * webapp.util.LoginManagerAction.loginJAAS(..)) && args( *, *, username, ..)")
public void pointcut2(String username) {
    doSomethingWithUsername(username);
}

private void doSomethingWithUsername(String username) {
    // inject the username into the MDC
    MDCUtils.setUsername(username);
}
```

I always split advices based on OR-ed pointcuts using bindings like that for each use-case (i.e. the pointcut expressions originally combined with `||`) because with `@annotation()` type pointcuts it results in an error message about *inconsistent binding*. See my two other answers about those cases and a similar solution to extract the common functionality to a separate method: [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426950/2699901), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36193862/2699901).

I believe AspectJ should exhibit the same behavior in your case as with `@annotation()` type pointcuts, so I think the compiler not reporting an error and doing unexpected things is a bug in the AspectJ compiler itself.

Comment: I posted to the aspectj-users list and Andy Clement confirmed that it is likely a bug in the pointcut rewriting (happens with .aj syntax as well).  I've raised a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509235.  In the meantime, I ended up doing exactly what you had suggested as well - I just find it to be more cluttered code though.

Comment: Thank you for submitting the bug report. I intended to do the same, I was just way too busy with my other tasks.